# How to formally verify a compiler (frontend and/or backend)?

Tags: compiler-construction, coq, theorem-proving, formal-verification, compcert

For a project I am about to begin, I was exploring formal verification of a compiler. I came across the [CompCert C Compiler](https://compcert.org/) which is an ACM awarded, formally verified C compiler.

When I read further, it mentioned that it has used [Coq Proof Assistant](https://coq.inria.fr/) to mechanise the automated verification.

The question is: *How does one go about creating the proofs/theorems for instruction translation? What are the steps?
Any guidance is welcome*.

Comment: https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/current/index.html - volume 1 is probably what you want.

Comment: @kiner_shah, this is a very good pointer, thanks! However, compiler specific steps are more welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Xavier Leroy has given a class at Collège de France on the topic in 2019/2020¹. The lessons themselves are in French, but the excellent material is available in English here: https://github.com/xavierleroy/cdf-mech-sem . In particular, the files `Imp.v` and `Compil.v` will give you an excellent head start on the basics.

However jumping in the Coq code directly is likely to be tricky. Visiting first or in parallel Software Foundation as pointed out by kiner_shah is an excellent idea.

¹: https://www.college-de-france.fr/agenda/cours/semantiques-mecanisees-quand-la-machine-raisonne-sur-ses-langages

Answer (score 1):

There is a much simpler compiler for pedagogical purposes in the coq-commmunity development named [semantics](https://github.com/coq-community/semantics/)

There is also a very elementary parser and more language related tools, like a tool to verify programs by weakest precondition, and an abstract interpreter (to prove that variables stay in some intervals).